# FormData causing error when received in php

Tags: php, multipartform-data

According to Mozilla documentation in FormData:

```
formData.append(name, value);
formData.append(name, value, filename);
```

Will work.  In my code I have the following:

```
formData.append('file', { uri: localUri, name: filename, type });
formData.append('details', 'Chris');
```

I then pass this formData object to a PHP rest server.
In my php server I have this code:

```
$data = $_FILES['file'];
$this->response($data,REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```

This works and gives me the appropriate response.  However this:

```
$data = $_FILES['details'];
```

Gives me an error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `details` is not from the `$_FILES` array - it is in the `$_POST` array

Comment: Ah man, you're right.  Should I delete question?